# Autorité vs Haute Autorité

Tags: international, name

In France, we have so called [Autorités Administratives Indépendantes](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autorit%C3%A9_administrative_ind%C3%A9pendante_en_France) which have various kind of names.

Is there a difference in the law between **Autorité** (for example `Autorité de sûreté nucléaire`) and **Haute Autorité** (for example `Haute Autorité de santé`) ?

Comment: I think that you are damaging your chances of getting an answer. There are far more likely to be English speaking who know French law in this forum than French speakers

Comment: Right, then I'm going to edit the post.